# Rate of movement at an RFID reader

Tags: velocity

I'm working at using RFID readers to track movement.  It's for a computer science project. I haven't done physics in a long time.
I'm using passive RFID tags.
This paper https://www.ee.washington.edu/research/seal/pubfiles/UbiComp_2004.pdf presents the idea of an RFID tag response rate. That is, the rate of response of RFID tags to signals sent by RFID readers.
Based on this, I'm making these assumptions:

1. If an RFID tag has the same response rate across consecutive time periods that the tag is stationary.
2. A change in response rate means the tag has moved.

So then I want to then propose that if the time taken for the tag to move is known and the rate of propagation of the signal is also known then the velocity of tag movement can be calculated.

Does this make sense?

Do I have to worry about the Doppler Effect?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not. The Doppler effect will  not decrease the speed of the signal, which seems to be all that you are relying on.